# How to get SNMP table in Python

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp

How is it possible to implement getting of SNMP table in Python + NetSnmp?

Simple set and get for Python + NetSNMP work fine:

```
myArgs = ['enterprises', 'set', '27142.1.1.20.1.2.1.1.1', '1', 'INTEGER']
var = netsnmp.Varbind(*myArgs)
res = netsnmp.snmpset(var, Version = 2, DestHost = 192.168.1.2, Community='private')
```

I would like to know how to implement the following NetSNMP command in Python:

```
snmptable -v 2c -c public -Ob 172.16.67.240 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to solve it unsuccessfully with getBulk in Python. It works quite strange returning only part of the table irrespective of getBulk parameters.
Solved it by directly invoking Linux shell from Python. Got the correct table in `out` variable:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['snmptable', '-v', '2c', '-c', 'public', '-Ob', '172.16.67.240',    '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

I would appreciate any better ideas!